# ESP8266-01 & Arduino Uno Problem

Tags: arduino-uno, esp8266, wifi, esp

I am having a problem when I want to run code like this on a Arduino Uno with esp8266-01. It's not working. In serial monitor nothing about esp.

```cpp
#include <SoftwareSerial.h> 
SoftwareSerial esp8266(2,3);

void setup() {
  // put your setup code here, to run once:
  Serial.begin(9600);
  esp8266.begin(9600);
  esp8266.print("AT+RST");
  delay(1000);
  esp8266.print("AT+CWMODE=1");
  esp8266.print("AT+CWJAP=\"ssisd\",\"pass\"");

}

void loop() {
  // put your main code here, to run repeatedly:

}
```

But when I load to Arduino empty code and to serial monitor write "AT" it working or I can connect to 
my wifi, but only with empty code.

[image]

RX is in pin 2 and TX is in pin 3.
And i flashing esp with this [Tutorial](https://create.arduino.cc/projecthub/pratikdesai/flash-firmware-on-esp8266-esp-01-module-e1f758)

Comment: It should be a cross-connection like TX -> RX, RX -> TX, your wiring is wrong.

Comment: The wiring also doesn't match the code.  The code is using SoftwareSerial on pins 2 and 3 to talk to the ESP8266.  In the drawing it is connected to the hardware serial pins 0 and 1.

Comment: to communicate with the esp-01, if you have an empty sketch in Uno, you connect the esp-01 to RX/TX of the USB chip on Uno. this chip is connected with TX to RX pin of Uno and with RX to Tx pin of Uno.

Comment: I had before TX and RX conected to pin 2 nad 3 i wrote this under picture. I tryed switch RX and TX still nothing.  I tryed RX in pin 0 and TX in pin 1 and change code, but still nothing.

Comment: Try changing baud to 115200 ?? Sometimes it's not 9600, I talk about esp8266.begin ...